# Rails how to query for a record based on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a **Friend model**:

```
user_id, friend_id, status (approved, pending, ignored)
```

I want to query if user1 & user 2 have a record.

```
user1.id = 10
user2.id = 9
```

The Friend Model could have either

```
10,9,x
9,10,x
```

How can I write a rails query that will see if a record exists, for either combination? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Friend.where(:user_id => [user.id, self.id], :friend_id => [user.id, self.id], :status => 'x')
```

Converted to SQL would be:

> "SELECT \"friends\".* FROM \"friends\" WHERE \"friends\".\"user_id\" IN (10, 9) AND \"friends\".\"friend_id\" IN (10, 9) AND \"friends\".\"status\" = 'x'"

It would return both cases with the one query:

```
[#<Friend id: 1, user_id: 10, friend_id: 9, status: 'x', created_at: "2011-06-25 15:09:00", updated_at: "2011-11-01 18:28:50">, #<Friend id: 2, user_id: 9, friend_id: 10, status: 'x', created_at: "2011-06-25 15:11:06", updated_at: "2011-11-01 18:28:50">]
```